# How to retrieve all nodes for a taxonomy term using Services?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, services

I want to retrieve all the nodes associated with a given taxonomy term (field_term) using HTTP GET.

I have tried:

```
curl -v http://myserver/endpoint_path/node?parameters[field_term]=1
```

but I get an HTTP 406 Column not found.

Also later on I will need to use multiple taxonomy vocabularies to filter by more than one term.

I am using the Services 3 module in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out how to do it, so I am posting it here in case it is helpful to somebody.
Feel free to post if you know a better way.

I assume you have created some content with fields corresponding to taxonomy vocabularies.

1. **Create a Services View**

   - Install the Services View module, as suggested in my previous comment.
   - Go to Structure / Views / Add new view
   - Give your view a name and uncheck 'create a page' because we just want a service.
   - Click 'Continue & Edit', you should then be in the 'Displays' screen.
   - Click on the '+Add' displays button, select 'Services'.
   - Under 'Service Settings' click on the path and change it. e.g my_view_path.
2. **Create criteria for your view**

   - Under 'Filter Criteria' click 'Add'. Do not use Advanced/Contextual Filters.
   - Search for your field, and click Apply'
   - 'Autocomplete' in the Selection Type, 'Apply and Continue'. It should not matter because we are going to call this from a URL, not a web page.
   - The 'Configure filter criterion' popover is shown.
   - Check 'Expose this filter to visitors'. If you don't do this, you will not be able to pass as an argument.
   - Scroll down to the bottom and click on 'More'.
   - Take note of the 'filter identifier'. This is the name of the argument you need to pass in the URL, e.g: field_myterm_tid
   - Click on Apply filter
   - Repeat for other filter criteria as needed.
   - Click on Save View
3. **Enable the Service Resource**

   - One last step, go to Structure > Services
   - You should see a list of endpoints, click 'Edit resources'
   - Check to enable the resource you just created.
4. **Finally, retrieve your info with HTTP GET**

`http: //myserver/my_endpoint_path/my_view_path?field_myterm_tid=XX&field_myterm2_tid=YY`

- XX and YY are the textual names of the terms

Answer (score 0):

Services in itself doesn't provide such specific use-cases.

You need a new resource, possibly you can find a module that provides what you are looking for, or you'll need to create a new one on your own.

The [Services views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) module appears like an excellent start for creating such resources.

Comment: Thank you. Filtering by a term should be a common enough use case, but I might be wrong. I am looking into the [services views module](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) and it looks promising

Comment: That looks like an absolutely excellent module. I'll update the answer with that as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 this can be done using json API module.

Install the module

Create a taxonomy color

Add vocabulary red, green and blue

Now to get all the vocabularies associated with the taxonomy color using get need to perform get on the following URL

```
http://localhost/drupal/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/color?_format=hal_json
```